# How to get the desired tag in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I'm having this problem in wordpress.
I want to be able to do something like:

1. "if the first tag of the post is "english" echo 'this'"
2. "if the second tag of the post is "spanish" echo 'that'"
3. "if the third tag of the post is "greek" echo 'those'"

So basically, I want to always identify the number of the tag and the name of the tag, to echo something special on each.
How can I do this?

Comment: Post your sample code here that you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has a function for it.

`get_the_tags();` function will return the number of tags associated with the current post.

For Ex:

```
$tagslist = get_the_tags();
foreach($tagslist as $tag) {
    if ($tag->name == "sometag" ) {
  // Do some stuffs
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but may be part of it.